# How to fix 'for loop' overwriting previous Array value

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I am retrieving information from my Firestore DB using a query. From debugging it appears that when I store the data in my ArrayList, each value overwrites the previous value. So only the final value is displaying in my ListView.

Various variation of my for loop. Trying to find a solution for approx 5 hours at this point.

```
public void addOrganisation(View view){
        db.collection("organisations").whereEqualTo("user", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){

                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){

                        Log.i(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.get("organisation"));

                        ArrayList<String> myOrgs = new ArrayList<String>(asList(document.get("organisation").toString()));

                        Log.i("ARRAY LIST", myOrgs.toString());

                        ListView myOrgsListView = findViewById(R.id.myOrgsListView);

                        ArrayAdapter<String> orgArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AppSettings.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myOrgs);
                        myOrgsListView.setAdapter(orgArrayAdapter);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Error getting documents:", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

LOG:

```
2019-04-17 13:46:02.694 1404-1418/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 30 syncs in 123s
2019-04-17 13:46:15.402 32372-32385/? I/UsageStatsService: User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
2019-04-17 13:46:17.150 32333-1938/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 99450911 , only wrote 99450720
2019-04-17 13:46:17.378 6108-6108/com.example.scrumpoker I/AppSettings: 6Euejc71xt7d2jvnB86Z => blahblah
2019-04-17 13:46:17.378 6108-6108/com.example.scrumpoker I/ARRAY LIST: [blahblah]
2019-04-17 13:46:17.380 6108-6108/com.example.scrumpoker I/AppSettings: 9RCJj725iVcpxKXMnOLo => blahblahblah
2019-04-17 13:46:17.380 6108-6108/com.example.scrumpoker I/ARRAY LIST: [blahblahblah]
2019-04-17 13:46:17.382 6108-6108/com.example.scrumpoker I/AppSettings: ZDzeIvTl5IRlcmcKsTfS => blahblahblahblah
2019-04-17 13:46:17.383 6108-6108/com.example.scrumpoker I/ARRAY LIST: [blahblahblahblah]
2019-04-17 13:46:17.383 6108-6108/com.example.scrumpoker I/AppSettings: y2Eiy2GmMTiW9rcwdL0u => stranger
2019-04-17 13:46:17.384 6108-6108/com.example.scrumpoker I/ARRAY LIST: [stranger]
2019-04-17 13:46:20.361 32333-5001/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 99757009 , only wrote 99604800
2019-04-17 13:46:31.306 31217-31233/? I/Finsky: [2039] hzb.run(3): Stats for Executor: BlockingExecutor ial@12fb4e9[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 96]
```

Expected: ListView populates with 4 values returned by the query

Actual: ListView populates with the final value returned by the query only.

Comment: the ArrayList initialization has to be outside the for loop. Every time it is creating new ArrayList inside the for loop hence you only see the last output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should be like this:

```
 public void addOrganisation(View view){
       ListView myOrgsListView = findViewById(R.id.myOrgsListView);
        db.collection("organisations").whereEqualTo("user", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    ArrayList<String> myOrgs = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){

                        Log.i(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.get("organisation"));

                        myOrgs.add(document.get("organisation").toString())

                        Log.i("ARRAY LIST", myOrgs.toString());

                    }
                     ArrayAdapter<String> orgArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AppSettings.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myOrgs);
                        myOrgsListView.setAdapter(orgArrayAdapter);
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Error getting documents:", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Please give some information about why it should be like that, and what you have done

Comment: what you were doing is initializing a new ArrayList inside your loop each time. Also, you were creating a new Adapter also inside your loop. So by the time, your loop finishes executing your ArrayList would have only the last element. Also a new orgArrayAdapter would be created for that particular list and would only display the last item in your listview.

Comment: Also it is bad for your performance to creating new instances each time in your loop

Comment: Thank you Vishal and @p.mathew13. I have been staring at the screen for too long, time for a break! **Thank you!!!**